# Passing local storage item to ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, local-storage

We have this code:

```
$.ajax({
            url:    localStorage.getItem("isntagram link"),
            // url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=233291163.8a612cd.c49f77de073746e9a2f53116b720302e",
            method: 'GET',
            dataType: 'jsonp',
```

Inside the local storage is a url to a JSON feed, the same link as the commented out url. The commented out code works but calling the same link from local storage is not.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

When I tried the code, it worked perfectly.

Check whether you have executed

```
localStorage.setItem("isntagram link", "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=233291163.8a612cd.c49f77de073746e9a2f53116b720302e");
```

before the `AJAX` call.

Note the spelling of **instagram** in your code.

A little spelling mistake can also be the reason for this error.

Check out this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/shrinivas93/eobqa7cn/1/).

Here is the snippet.

```js
localStorage.setItem("instagram link", "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=233291163.8a612cd.c49f77de073746e9a2f53116b720302e");

$.ajax({
  url: localStorage.getItem("instagram link"),
  // url: "https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/feed?access_token=233291163.8a612cd.c49f77de073746e9a2f53116b720302e",
  method: 'GET',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```